# Identity provider oauth callback error to keycloak 502

Tags: keycloak

I am running keycloak 19.0.2 in dev mode. When trying to login to microsoft from `keycloak` (SSO) using the oauth2 flow, I get 502 error in the browser on the callback to `keycloak`. The code param has a strange value also.

I believe it has something to do with user permissions, but I can clearly see I have defined them.[image]

The callback to the keycloak server throws a 502 error and has strange values in the code params.

[image]

The keycloak server errors with the following logs:

```
 2022-10-17 13:08:46,517 ERROR 
 [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (executor-thread-42) 
 Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: 
 org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: Could not obtain user profile 
 from Microsoft Graph

2022-10-17 13:08:46,542 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-42) 
type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=8ca06b23-d544-4464-a3bf-448be5308802, 
clientId=recruit-api, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, 
error=identity_provider_login_failure, code_id=62aaf7bf-9c08-4c88-a7c3-e6f7af282de1, 
authSessionParentId=62aaf7bf-9c08-4c88-a7c3-e6f7af282de1, 
authSessionTabId=WjArYJ99WyM
```